# Generate two columns from two different sized ranges with one formula

Tags: google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, I have a series of test cases, each arranged in three columns and one row: an ID, a title, and a series of steps.

[image: three test cases arranged in 3x1 cells]

I need to split the steps into multiple cells in a column, while keeping the ID alongside the first row of each test case.

I can do this with separate formulas in two adjacent columns. (Column A contains the IDs, C contains the steps, H contains the steps separated into separate rows, and G contains the IDs to line up with H.)

```
=IF(ROW()=1, A1,
IF(REGEXMATCH(H1, "^-\s"), INDIRECT("A"&(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("G1:G"&ROW()-1), "Q-*")+1)),
""
))
```

```
=TOCOL(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(C1:C3, "
- ", false)), 1, false)
```

The above results in this:
[image]

But I think it's possible to do this with one formula. How? I don't want the ID next to every step, just the first one in each test case. Each test case can have a different number of steps, so it's not possible to just insert X blank rows after each ID.

Here's a [test spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11m5BLZUKmwnolvnMly5svezhCHiC-A_F55U2YpxrK30/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```js
=reduce(tocol(,1),A1:index(A:A,match(,0/(A:A<>""))),lambda(a,c,iferror(vstack(a,hstack(c,tocol(split(offset(c,,2),char(10))))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following method, which consists of 6 parts:

**First**, we'll add a 2nd delimiter " #" (you can select a special character you want) before each line. Make sure to add a space before the delimiter:
[image]

**2nd**, we'll concatenate the ID to the result above:
[image]

**3rd**, we can now split it using the line break as delimiter:
[image]

**4th**, let's convert the result above into one column using FLATTEN:
[image]

**5th**, we remove the blanks:
[image]

**Finally**, we'll split the above result using the 2nd delimiter that we've added in the 1st step:
[image]

Here's the **final formula**:

```
=ArrayFormula(LET(add2ndDelim,SUBSTITUTE(C1:C3,"-"," #-"),
                  concatID,A1:A3&add2ndDelim,
                  split1st,SPLIT(concatID,CHAR(10)),
                  vertList,FLATTEN(split1st),
                  removeBlanks,FILTER(vertList,vertList<>""),
                  finalSplit,SPLIT(removeBlanks,"#"),
                  finalSplit))
```